# Basic RMA issue with MPI_Win_create, Null pointer in parameter NULL base pointer is invalid when size is nonzero

Tags: fortran, window, mpi

I'm working in Fortran 90 with the latest stable version of MPICH (3.3)

I want to have an MPI_Window expose an array on the root process, and all other processes in the communicator call MPI_Get to copy the array into their own "local" copy.

Unfortunately, providing MPI_BOTTOM as the "base" argument in the non-root processes for [MPI_Win_create](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2.x/www3/MPI_Win_create.html)(base, ...) results in the error

> MPI_Win_create(192): MPI_Win_create(base=(nil), size=0, disp_unit=1275069467, MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_WORLD, win=0x7ffcb343d9fc) failed
>
> MPI_Win_create(156): Null pointer in parameter NULL base pointer is invalid when size is nonzero

I've been working off a textbook example, pg. 61 Fig 3.2, Using Advanced MPI, Modern Features of the Message-Passing Interface, Gropp, Hoefler, Thakur, Lusk.

What is the alternative `kind(MPI_ADDRESS_KIND)` that I'm supposed to use besides `MPI_BOTTOM`? Is this the correct way to initialize an MPI_Window on a process which isn't actually exposing it's internal memory, just accessing that of another process?

Obviously, changing the argument for base to an already allocated (non-null) array works, but this changes the behavior of the later GET so it doesn't work (creates an invalid memory access).

I don't know why the runtime error specifically says that a null base pointer is invalid with nonzero size, since I'm clearly specifying the size as 0 in the call to `mpi_win_create(MPI_BOTTOM, 0, MPI_INTEGER, ...)`.

Here's all the code I have for this example for myself. It sets up the buffers and attempts to create the windows for each process. There is a commented out section between two calls to `MPI_Fence` that is the section where all non-root processes attempt the GET.

```
program main
  use mpi

  implicit none
  integer :: ierr, procno, nprocs, comm

  integer, allocatable :: root_data(:), local_data(:)
  integer, parameter :: root = 0, NUM_ELEMENTS = 10

  integer :: win

  integer :: i

  !======================================

  call mpi_init(ierr)
  comm = mpi_comm_world
  call mpi_comm_rank(comm, procno, ierr)
  call mpi_comm_size(comm, nprocs, ierr)

  !======================================
  if (procno .eq. root) then
    allocate(root_data(1:NUM_ELEMENTS))
    do i=1,NUM_ELEMENTS
      root_data(i) = i
    enddo

    call mpi_win_create(root_data, NUM_ELEMENTS, MPI_INTEGER, &
                        MPI_INFO_NULL, comm, win, ierr)
  else
    allocate(local_data(1:NUM_ELEMENTS))
    local_data = 0
    call mpi_win_create(MPI_BOTTOM, 0, MPI_INTEGER, &
                        MPI_INFO_NULL, comm, win, ierr)
  endif

  !======================================
  call mpi_win_fence(0, win, ierr)
 
  !if (procno .ne. root) then 
  !  call mpi_get(local_data, NUM_ELEMENTS, MPI_INTEGER, &
  !               root, 0, NUM_ELEMENTS, MPI_INTEGER, &
  !               win, ierr)
  !endif

  call mpi_win_fence(0, win, ierr)
  !======================================

  if (procno .ne. root) then
    print *, "proc", procno
    print *, local_data
  endif

  !======================================
  call MPI_Win_free(win, ierr)

  call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program main
```

The expected result is that each process prints its version of `local_data`., which in this case should be ten 0's since the MPI_Get is commented out.

I hit the runtime error instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `size` argument of `MPI_Win_create()` has type `INTEGER(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND)`.

I was then able to successfully run the modified version with both MPICH 3.3 and the latest Open MPI

```
program main
  use mpi

  implicit none
  integer :: ierr, procno, nprocs, comm

  integer, allocatable :: root_data(:), local_data(:)
  integer, parameter :: root = 0
  integer (KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: NUM_ELEMENTS = 10, zero = 0

  integer :: win

  integer :: i

  !======================================

  call mpi_init(ierr)
  comm = mpi_comm_world
  call mpi_comm_rank(comm, procno, ierr)
  call mpi_comm_size(comm, nprocs, ierr)

  !======================================
  if (procno .eq. root) then
    allocate(root_data(1:NUM_ELEMENTS))
    do i=1,NUM_ELEMENTS
      root_data(i) = i
    enddo

    call mpi_win_create(root_data, NUM_ELEMENTS, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_INFO_NULL, comm, win, ierr)
  else
    allocate(local_data(1:NUM_ELEMENTS))
    local_data = 0
    call mpi_win_create(MPI_BOTTOM, zero, MPI_INTEGER, MPI_INFO_NULL, comm, win, ierr)
  endif

  !======================================
  call mpi_win_fence(0, win, ierr)

  !if (procno .ne. root) then 
  !  call mpi_get(local_data, NUM_ELEMENTS, MPI_INTEGER, &
  !               root, 0, NUM_ELEMENTS, MPI_INTEGER, &
  !               win, ierr)
  !endif

  call mpi_win_fence(0, win, ierr)
  !======================================

  if (procno .ne. root) then
    print *, "proc", procno
    print *, local_data
  endif

  !======================================
  call MPI_Win_free(win, ierr)

  call mpi_finalize(ierr)
end program main
```

Comment: Thanks! That would make a ton of sense. In the later call to MPI_Get, which is commented out in the OP, I made a change to 

`call mpi_get(..., root, MPI_BOTTOM, ...)`

Which resulted in the expected output of printing 1:NUM_ELEMENTS from the local_data(:) array for each process. 

But I don't really understand why this has occurred. 

Is it because in terms of the shared memory region that is provided on the `root` process, the array is located at the start of the shared memory region? 

Best,
Sam

Comment: I guess you are referring to the `MPI_Aint target_disp` argument following `int target_rank`. The standard requires an offset (relative to the beginning of the window) and not an address. Strictly speaking, `MPI_BOTTOM` is an incorrect value here but you are lucky it is equivalent to `NULL` (in the MPI library you are using).